# Black screen with mouse pointer on boot, KDE Neon

Tags: boot, drivers, kde, nvidia, kde5

## Preface:

I have a Lenovo Z50, 4GB RAM. I tried installing **KDE Neon 5.15.4** (based on Ubuntu 18.04) on it, but I am getting problems. I am a noob, so question may be over-descriptive.

## Problem:

The first time I installed, the installation went perfect (I had chosen to install additional extras), and I chose "try OS for some time" over "reboot now" option.

But when I booted into the installed OS, after the initial splash screen, it threw dialogue boxes saying `ksplashqml` crashed and 2 or 3 more of them (I unexpectedly closed them as `ksplashqml`'s box took some time to close), so I don't know what else crashed.

After that, I was left with a black screen with a pointer. I waited for quite some time and pressed the power button for a long time (forced power off). I rebooted but got the same black screen with the pointer, no dialogue boxes this time. Again, I forced power off.

## What I have tried:

1. Some said to not install any extras while installing, so installed KDE Neon again by wiping the entire disk.

   After installation, I chose "`reboot now`" option and the OS booted, though it took quite some time to load the desktop after splash screen. Then, everything was working good, I updated (to **KDE 5.16.4**) using `pkcon refresh` and `pkcon update`, installed NVIDIA driver (340 in my case) with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, and rebooted. I was again greeted with black screen with the pointer, no dialogue boxes.
2. Then I came to know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

   I went to **tty2**, logged in but couldn't do anything. Then I found out about `startx`. So, after logging in **tty2**, I typed `startx` and hit enter, and I was greeted with `ksplashqml` crashed dialogue, but taking its time the desktop loaded this time.

   I have attached the log from the dialogue box. Also, it shows `rendering with software is enabled` when I reach the desktop this way. The desktop becomes still and non-operative after some time (closing a window usually triggers it), and also if I launch discover and then close it (even just after startup).

   Sometimes even the `ksmserver-logout-greeter` crashes (log attached). Sometimes the resolution is lower.
3. Booting to grub (using <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and replacing `ro quiet splash` with `nomodeset quiet spalsh` or just `nomodeset` in grub (by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> for editing).
4. Disabling blur effect.
5. Changing kernel version (5, 4.18, 4.15.18).
6. Blacklisting **nouveau** driver (I have whitelisted it now, don't know how to check, by removing line `blacklist nouveau` and `options nouveau modeset=0` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf` file which I had added following [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) guide).

Do I have any options left? I can run terminal commands from Konsole (**tty2**).

## Logs:

**`ksplashqml`** crash log:

```
Application: ksplashqml (ksplashqml), signal: Aborted
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f731c206d00 (LWP 1104))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f7305a05700 (LWP 1107)):
#0  0x00007f73193740b4 in __GI___libc_read (fd=8, buf=0x7f7305a04af0, nbytes=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:27
#1  0x00007f7311fbaf55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.107
#2  0x00007f7313d032d0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f7313cbe0b7 in g_main_context_check () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f7313cbe570 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f7313cbe6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007f7319cbbdcb in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f7319c5d03a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f7319a844ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007f7318ccc115 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#10 0x00007f7319a85c72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f7316cd56db in start_thread (arg=0x7f7305a05700) at pthread_create.c:463
#12 0x00007f731938588f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f7306632700 (LWP 1106)):
#0  __lll_unlock_wake () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:371
#1  0x00007f7316cd97df in __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt (decr=1, mutex=0x7f7315aa88a0) at pthread_mutex_unlock.c:54
#2  __GI___pthread_mutex_unlock (mutex=0x7f7315aa88a0) at pthread_mutex_unlock.c:345
#3  0x00007f7315824b79 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
#4  0x00007f7315828888 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
#5  0x00007f7311fbafe1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.107
#6  0x00007f7313d032d0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007f7313cbe0b7 in g_main_context_check () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#8  0x00007f7313cbe570 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007f7313cbe6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007f7319cbbdcb in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007f7319c5d03a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x00007f7319a844ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f731ab60015 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#14 0x00007f7319a85c72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f7316cd56db in start_thread (arg=0x7f7306632700) at pthread_create.c:463
#16 0x00007f731938588f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f731c206d00 (LWP 1104)):
[KCrash Handler]
#5  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#6  0x00007f73192a4801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#7  0x00007f7319a61f2b in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007f731b40978d in QSGRenderLoop::handleContextCreationFailure(QQuickWindow*, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#9  0x00007f731b40a57d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#10 0x00007f731b40b31a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#11 0x00007f731a233655 in QWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#12 0x00007f731b487025 in QQuickWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#13 0x00007f7319c5ed18 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f731a22919a in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::ExposeEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#15 0x00007f731a2293ed in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#16 0x00007f731a201b4b in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#17 0x00007f7309c0d59a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#18 0x00007f7313cbe417 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007f7313cbe650 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007f7313cbe6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007f7319cbbdaf in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#22 0x00007f7319c5d03a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f7319c66170 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#24 0x000056487af83c06 in ?? ()
#25 0x00007f7319285b97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x56487af83ab0, argc=3, argv=0x7ffe0358c338, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffe0358c328) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#26 0x000056487af83cda in _start ()
```

**`ksmserver-logout-greeter` crash log:**

```
Application: ksmserver-logout-greeter (ksmserver-logout-greeter), signal: Aborted
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fe340e68880 (LWP 3361))]

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fe321518700 (LWP 3364)):
#0  0x00007fe33c52ebf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fe3140025e0, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fe334fdc5c9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fe334fdc6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fe33ce71dcb in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fe33ce1303a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fe33cc3a4ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fe33ef6c115 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5
#7  0x00007fe33cc3bc72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fe33702f6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fe321518700) at pthread_create.c:463
#9  0x00007fe33c53b88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fe322b55700 (LWP 3363)):
#0  0x00007fe33c52a0b4 in __GI___libc_read (fd=6, buf=0x7fe322b54ae0, nbytes=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:27
#1  0x00007fe331c39f55 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.107
#2  0x00007fe3350212d0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fe334fdc0b7 in g_main_context_check () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fe334fdc570 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007fe334fdc6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#6  0x00007fe33ce71dcb in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007fe33ce1303a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x00007fe33cc3a4ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fe33daca015 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#10 0x00007fe33cc3bc72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x00007fe33702f6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fe322b55700) at pthread_create.c:463
#12 0x00007fe33c53b88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fe3289c2700 (LWP 3362)):
#0  0x00007fe33c52ebf9 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fe3289c1c28, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fe337692747 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#2  0x00007fe33769436a in xcb_wait_for_event () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
#3  0x00007fe32b17f578 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#4  0x00007fe33cc3bc72 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fe33702f6db in start_thread (arg=0x7fe3289c2700) at pthread_create.c:463
#6  0x00007fe33c53b88f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fe340e68880 (LWP 3361)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#7  0x00007fe33c45a801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#8  0x00007fe33cc17f2b in QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fe33f6c478d in QSGRenderLoop::handleContextCreationFailure(QQuickWindow*, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#10 0x00007fe33f6c557d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#11 0x00007fe33f6c631a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#12 0x00007fe33d3e9655 in QWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#13 0x00007fe33f742025 in QQuickWindow::event(QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Quick.so.5
#14 0x000055d845f38c21 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fe33e0a465c in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#16 0x00007fe33e0abb90 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#17 0x00007fe33ce14d18 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#18 0x00007fe33d3df19a in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::ExposeEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#19 0x00007fe33d3df3ed in QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#20 0x00007fe33d3b7b4b in QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#21 0x00007fe32b18059a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
#22 0x00007fe334fdc417 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007fe334fdc650 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007fe334fdc6dc in g_main_context_iteration () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007fe33ce71daf in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#26 0x00007fe33ce1303a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#27 0x00007fe33ce1c170 in QCoreApplication::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#28 0x000055d845f34a95 in ?? ()
#29 0x00007fe33c43bb97 in __libc_start_main (main=0x55d845f347e0, argc=1, argv=0x7ffe73654f28, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffe73654f18) at ../csu/libc-start.c:310
#30 0x000055d845f34bba in _start ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

After trying KDE Neon, I switched to Pop! OS and it threw message that it couldn't boot because of security policies of computer. I had Secure Boot enabled in BIOS. I couldn't see the option for Secure Boot at first and had to set Boot Mode to UEFI in BIOS. Secure Boot seems to block some graphic drivers, but I am amazed how the OS booted at all!

Another problem might be NVIDIA Optimus(switchable or hybrid graphics), in which case [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Anyone-Have-Working-Hybrid-Graphics-on-Linux/td-p/4357559) might be useful.

I am on Kubuntu now, btw. :)

Hope it helps!